# bootstrap portfolio images & modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I m making a site with Bootstrap in French and i have a section called Services Francophones  it is like a portfolio with different  pictures of   services. Now i did reduce the size of the 8 first pictures so they are smaller and have a padding between each other. But the padding is to big  in my css

```
.metier-item img {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     /*margin-right: 10px;*/
}
```

I added a margin-bottom of 10 px that work perfectly. Now i was trying to reduce the margin between the pictures..so i added margin-right of 10px but the space between the pictures stay the same but the title form each image get push away. how do i get to have the same margin between each picture i want them closer from each other. [link to website](http://www.mgbourgeois.com/floride/)  in the navbar click on services francophones.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you right. You want see images which looks like the same width.

```
// Stretch the picture
.metier-item img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

// play with indentation by padding
.metier-item .metier-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px; 
}

.metier-item .metier-link:hover {} //delete

.metier-item:hover {
     transform: scale(1.04);
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Olga! It works perfectly... I do like the way it looks! But let s say i wish  to push the images so there is more space on each side like in the graphic at www.mgbourgeois.com/floride/services.png I want to push the images so there are more centered but still have 10px between other???  i tried different things but the title in the image are then displace. Thanks!

Comment: O! I found. I changed my answer above. Problem was in .metier-item - it has overflow: hidden; It means we can't use scale for children.

Comment: Thanks again Olga ! i applied the change and there is no difference!!! i appreciated your help! I will leave it this way it look good on all devices. have a great day